# C# function to return nothing if condition not satisfied

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a WPF/C# application, in the application I have this function:

```
private char getLastChar()
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        return textBox1.Text[textBox1.Text.Length - 1];
}
```

if I keep it like this, I get an error:

```
MainWindow.getLastChar()': not all code paths return a value
```

How can I set this to work?

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you call the function?

Comment: @SLaks♦: this function should return the last character from the textbox if the length is greater than ZERO, meaning the textbox contains at least 1 character.

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you call the function if it doesn't have one character?  It doesn't make sense to return "nothing"; what would the caller get?

Comment: The applications works when there is at least one character in the textBox. So if the textBox if empty, then the application will do nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PRE-EDIT:

Given that you've said in the comments that "If the textbox is empty, the program should do nothing", why not just do this:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    //DO STUFF HERE
}
else
{
    //DO NOTHING HERE
}
```

If you really need to return a null value, you can use one of these two options:

```
private char? getLastChar()
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        return textBox1.Text[textBox1.Text.Length - 1];
    else
        return null;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
char? lastCharInTextBox = getLastChar();
if (lastCharInTextBox == null)
{
    //Do something about empty text box
}
else
{
   char myVar = lastCharInTextBox.Value;
   //Do something with the character inside "myVar"
}
```

Chars are value types, which means that they cannot be set to null references. Using a question mark will make the char nullable.

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
private char getLastChar()
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        return textBox1.Text[textBox1.Text.Length - 1];
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This would return a normal char, but would return a null terminator character if the textbox has no text.

Comment: it didn`t work, I got this error this time "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char?' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @sikas - Well you need to check if the char is null. So in your code, you'll need to do: `If (returnValueFromFunction != null) someVariable = returnValueFromFunction.Value;`. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. You can find more examples of using nullable type here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: it finally worked, I had to change the initialization of the char in the other function to char? and the function to be private char? getLastChar()

Answer (score 2):

Your only return is in a conditional statement.

You must have something being returned outside of that if statement.

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to return if `textBox.Text.Length > 0`? The function has to return something, but in your example above it only returns if the condition is satisfied, which it may not be.

Comment: if the string contains at least 1 character, the last character is returned, else nothing is returned. As returning anything will crash the application then!

Comment: @sikas: Karl Nicoll's example's that uses the nullable char (`char?`) is your best option then.

Comment: @sikas: Yes, if you have a `char` variable that you're setting it to, then that will need to be changed to `char?`.  You'll also need to either check if it's null, or use [HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.80).aspx) to see if it's set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have heard of MVC, you will know that this is something you need to check in the controller. The controller should make sure your text box is not empty and then, the code you have written (and which should be in the model) will be invoked. This is good software engineering practice.

In simple words, check if the TextBox is empty (somewhere else in your code) and then conditionally make a call to getLastChar().

Alternatively, you can check for the length and return null, but you would have to handle the null value at some place eventually. So, check the size of the TextBox before making the function call and get yourself some reusable code.